# Wordpress Creating Blog Postings by Specific Category

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm working on a blog and currently when I load the initial blog page all the posts show up properly. However, whenever I used my sidebar navigation to go to another page my query becomes incorrect and I can't get any posts to show.

This is my index page for the blog:

```
<div class="single-page-bg">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
            <div class="main-copy-sidebar">
                <?php get_sidebar('news'); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="main-copy-container">
            <h1 class="news-header">NEWS</h1>
            <div>
                <?php
                    if ( have_posts() ) : 
                        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                            echo "have posts";
                            get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
                        endwhile;
                    else :
                        echo "no posts";
                        get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );
                    endif;
                ?>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.main-copy-container -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my sidebar navigation:

```
<a class="sidebar-trigger" data-action="sidebar-trigger"><span class="label">RELATED CONTENT</span><span class="arrow white-arrow-down"></span>    </a>
<div class="sidebar-accordion"  data-active="0">
  <div class="sidebar-content">
        <div class="page-sidebar">

            <div class="sidebar-header">
                <h3>CATEGORIES</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar-body">
                <?php 

                $cats = get_categories(); 
                foreach($cats as $cat){
                $category_id = get_cat_ID( $cat->slug );
                $category_link = get_category_link ($category_id);
                echo "<a href=\"".$category_link."\" class=\"btn btn-subnav-item btn-narrow-container\">".$cat->name."</a>";
                }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- /.page-sidebar -->
<div class="sidebar-buttons"></div><!-- /.sidebar-buttons -->
```

This is where my content is being loaded:

```
<article class="main-copy news-article">
        <?php 
            $uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; // Get the URI
            $uri_array = split("/",$uri); // Split the URI via /'s
            $uri_url = $uri_array[2]; // might need to change this to [1]
            $uri_category = $uri_array[3]; // Get the category to sort by
        ?>

        <?php
        // The Query
            $query = new WP_Query( array(
                'taxonomy' => '$uri_category',
                'order' => 'DESC'
            ));

            if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                echo "true";
            while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                $query->the_post();?>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            <?php }
        } else {
            // no posts found
        }
        ?>

        <?php if ($uri_url = "category" && $uri_category != NULL) { 
            //Testing my uri request
        } ?>

    <?php
        if ( is_single() ) :
            the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title">', '</h2>' );
        else :
            the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title outside"><a href="' . convert_reno_link(esc_url( get_permalink() )) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' );
        endif;
        ?>
        <div class="meta">
            <p class="meta-date"><time><?php the_date('F j, Y'); ?></time></p>
        </div>
    <?php 



        // the_content(); 
        $image_id = get_field('featured_image');
      $xsmall_breakpoint = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id, 'xsmall_breakpoint' );
      $args = array(
        'images' => array(
          array(
            'src' =>$xsmall_breakpoint[0],
         )
        ),
        'fallback_src' => $xsmall_breakpoint[0],
        'class' => $class
      );

        if ( is_single() ) {
          writePicturefill($args);
            the_content();
        } else {

            if($image_id){
            ?>
            <div class="article-image">
                <?php
                  writePicturefill($args);
                ?>
            </div><div class="article-body">
            <?php } ?>
            <?php
                $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
                echo $excerpt;
                echo "&nbsp;<a href=\"".convert_reno_link(esc_url( get_permalink() ))."\">Learn more</a>";
            if($image_id){ ?></div><?php }
        }
    ?>  
</article><!-- /.main-copy -->
```

Like I said the initial blog page loads in my index file where it has posts and the content page works properly. However, once I click on my sidebar navigation it goes to its new page where I believe the query is changed and isn't returning any posts. My sidebar navigation is essentially a list of the categories available. The most important part to take away from the third bit of code is the top bit where I'm trying to work with the query itself. Below that is just how I use the returned values to output the content.

tl;dr: How can I make these category pages return a query with posts in it?

Response to JudeRosario. Here's my content with a wp_reset_query().

```
<?php
        // The Query
            $query = new WP_Query( array(
                'taxonomy' => '$uri_category',
                'order' => 'DESC'
            ));

            if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                // echo "true";
                while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                    $query->the_post();?>
                    <!-- <?php the_excerpt(); ?> -->
                <?php }
            } else {
                // no posts found
            }
            wp_reset_query();
        ?>
```

Here's my sidebar foreach with a wp_reset_query():

```
<div class="sidebar-body">
                <?php 

                $cats = get_categories(); 
                foreach($cats as $cat){
                $category_id = get_cat_ID( $cat->slug );
                $category_link = get_category_link ($category_id);
                echo "<a href=\"".$category_link."\" class=\"btn btn-subnav-item btn-narrow-container\">".$cat->name."</a>";
                }
                wp_reset_query();
                ?>
          </div>
```

I'm now getting a single post showing up on my category pages. However, it's a single post on each page and it's the same post on each page.

Comment: You need to reset the query after each Loop. Call this function `wp_reset_query()` once the Loop is done in both places.

Comment: Where exactly do I want these query resets?

Comment: Right after the `foreach` loop and right after the `if` and `else` statements.

Comment: Would love to try these out...however, as soon as I went to reload my page one more time it now doesn't want to load at all.

Comment: Post your final code here after my suggestions

Comment: I put the new code in response to you in my main section. I'm done work atm but i'll be checking on this early in the morning and probably throughout the night from time to time.

Comment: Hey when you come back 1) Remove reset function from the categories. 2) Also the code is a bit off functions like `the_title()` must be used inside the Loop